# Import PostGIS layer to QGIS 2.2 based on detailed query

Tags: postgis, qgis

With QGIS 1.7 I used the PostGIS Query Editor daily to run relatively complex queries and view the result. I upgraded to QGIS 2.2 (which I like much better) but I'm not seeing any plugins that fulfill that role and can be used in 2.2.

Am I missing something, is there a way to execute a full query like `SELECT * FROM geofile JOIN nongeofile ON geofile.id=nongeofile.id`?

ZR

Comment: I agree. QGIS 2.2 is a major upgrade.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the DB Manager plugin now, see: https://www.qgis.org/en/docs/user_manual/plugins/plugins_db_manager.html

Note that you have to create the connections first in QGIS browser.

Comment: Thanks. The DB Manager is a nice feature. It does seem a bit clunky to me though. I'm not sure why it requires a unique field to be loaded into the map. I'm also not sure why it can't at least make a guess to what the geometry field would be. But this will work. Thanks!

Comment: Agreed, though it is a good practice to have a primary key generally. Whenever I find myself irritated with any FOSS4G software, I usually find five minutes with ArcGIS to be a good cure. :-)

Comment: Maybe you can chime in on what I'm doing wrong here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41176146/using-qgis-how-to-properly-link-a-postgis-sql-layer

Comment: @chrismarx. Sorry, I can't. These days I do all my analysis in Postgres/Postgis and only use QGIS to visualize results, which I do by dumping using pgsql2shp. I work on very large datasets and find the QGIS -> Postgres link to be too slow.

Comment: Yeah. That's where I am too :(